# Distributed Tensorflow: worker killed due to OOM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm running distributed tensorflow training similar to the [Inception sample code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py) but using this device setter:

```
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(ps_tasks=1,
                                              worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_id,
                                              cluster=cluster_spec)):
```

The machine has 4 GPUs and 64 GB RAM. The `ps` job is running on CPU alone, and have two `worker` jobs running on 2 separate GPUs. The res memory footprint of both worker jobs gradually keeps increasing until around 3000 steps, the chief worker gets killed by OOM (both workers are occupying ~49% RAM before the crash). I have tried with a single worker too and that one gets killed too. The `ps` job has a much smaller footprint.
I have tried disabling summary ops, model saver, variables averager, reduced reader threads, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue with the workers by commenting the `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):` spec while calling `batch_inputs` in [`image_processing.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py#L132). One reason this may have happened with my setup though not completely clear is that I use

```
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(ps_tasks=1,
                                              worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_id,
                                              cluster=cluster_spec)):
```

instead of

```
# Ops are assigned to worker by default.
with tf.device('/job:worker/task:%d' % FLAGS.task_id):
    # Variables and its related init/assign ops are assigned to ps.
    with slim.scopes.arg_scope(
            [slim.variables.variable, slim.variables.global_step],
            device=slim.variables.VariableDeviceChooser(num_parameter_servers)):
```

as the outermost training scope inside which the batch processing gets called ([`inception_distributed_train.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py#L113)).

Not sure why exactly this became a problem for my modified setup (owing to no documentation about the mechanics of how device assignments are made), but now the memory increase trend has reduced at least ten-fold, and tested to run for a 100 epochs.

Maybe the original code will work fine without this CPU device specification as well.